# NSArray with nested objects "losing" objects in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

So in a block I am getting and parsing a JSON object that looks like this (any time you see "<...>" assume properly formed data)(also this is only one of the objects in question):

```
{
    asset =         {
        <...>
    };
    <...>
    sections =         (
                    {
            <...>
            fields =                 (
            );
            items =                 (
            );
        },
                    {
            <...>
            fields =                 (
            );
            items =                 (
            );

        },
                    {
            <...>
            fields =                 (
            );
            items =                 (
                                    {
                    <...>
                    properties =                         {
                        title = "We welcome guests...";
                    };
                },
                                    {
                    <...>
                    properties =                         {
                        title = "More text";
                    };
                },
                                    {
                    <...>
                    properties =                         {
                        title = "Opportunity Insert...";
                    };
                }
            );
        },
                    {
            <...>
            fields =                 (
                                    {
                    <...>
                    values =                         (
                        Private,
                        Public
                    );
                },
                                    {
                    <...>
                    values =                         (
                    );
                },
                                    {
                    <...>
                    values =                         (
                    );
                }
            );
            items =                 (
            );
        },
                    {
            <...>
            fields =                 (
                                    {
                    <...>
                    values =                         (
                    );
                },
                                    {
                    <...>
                    values =                         (
                    );
                }
            );
            items =                 (
            );
        }
    );
}
```

The code to get this(using AFNetworking):

```
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AppsURL([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kAuthToken])]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
[op setResponseSerializer:[[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc] init]];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (responseObject != nil&&[responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
        if (dict[@"apps"]&&[dict[@"apps"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            apps = dict[@"apps"];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
            return;
        }

    }
        NSLog(@"Error Loading apps:%@",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    NSLog(@"Response:%@",operation.response.description);

}];

[op start];
```

At this point everything is loading into memory and working perfectly. I set this to a class-level NSArray and then use that NSArray to fill a table. The problem comes when I try to retrieve the data after the user picks one of the items from the table. I then use the index and pull that object from the NSArray to find that is looks like this(note the fact that all item and field arrays are now empty):

```
{
asset =     {
    <...>
};
<...>
sections =     (
            {
        <...>
        fields =             (
        );
        items =             (
        );
    },
            {
        <...>
        fields =             (
        );
        items =             (
        );
    },
            {
        <...>
        fields =             (
        );
        items =             (
        );
    },
            {
        <...>
        fields =             (
        );
        items =             (
        );
    }
);
}
```

Code for select:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  if (indexPath.row < apps.count) {
    //the output of this is what I copy and pasted
    NSLog(@"app data to be cleaned up:%@ \r app data sent:%@",apps[indexPath.row],((NSDictionary*)apps[indexPath.row]).mutableCopy);

    //I originally thought the problem was here, but the output above proved me wrong
    NSMutableDictionary *app = [Functions recurseDictionaryForNull:((NSDictionary*)apps[indexPath.row]).mutableCopy];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:app
                                              forKey:@"app"];

    MainMenuViewController* mainMenu = (MainMenuViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenu"];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[mainMenu] animated:YES];// reset nav stack
  }
}
```

I'm kinda at a lose... any ideas what could be doing this and how to fix it??

Comment: There's not enough info here for anyone to help you. You should provide the relevant code that creates and accesses this array.

Comment: Added code, please don't down vote before someone gets a chance to respond... kinda rude.

Comment: Someone else downvoted you, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the call out then.

Comment: If the class-level `apps` contains non-empty nested arrays for `fields` and `items` at the point the table is filled but they are empty later at row selection, then I suggest you debug the code in between - is the code that you haven't shown that fills the table manipulating `apps` or any copy of any row in it?  Also just a reminder that `mutableCopy` on a NSDictionary is NOT a deep copy - your nested `fields` and `items` are not copies.

Comment: The apps NSArray is never manipulated. The only time it's even accessed is to check the count of it and to read one key per "app" to fill in the cells in the table, but again, it's just reading the data, not manipulating it. That mutableCopy bit is VERY useful to know, but unfortunately doesn't explain the fields and items being missing before calling it(i.e. in the NSLog output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the data from the server. I was told 2 "apps" were the same except for one item and turns out they were missing all of the fields and items as well. Thanks Dima and Mike for taking the time anyways!